# Unable to set a key as 'redisClusterCommand()' is returning null pointer

Tags: c++, c, redis, hiredis

I'm trying to run a simple program which will insert a key-value into my redis cluster of 6 instances(3 master,3 replica). I'm using [hiredis-vip](https://github.com/vipshop/hiredis-vip/blob/master/hircluster.h).

Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <hircluster.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
struct timeval timeout = { 1, 500000 }; // 1.5 seconds
redisClusterContext *cc = redisClusterContextInit();
redisClusterSetOptionAddNodes(cc, "172.16.129.68:6379");
redisClusterSetOptionConnectTimeout(cc, timeout);
redisClusterConnect2(cc);
if (cc != NULL && cc->err) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", cc->errstr);
    // handle error
exit(-1);
}
redisReply *reply;
    reply = (redisReply*)(redisClusterCommand(cc,"SET %s %s", "foo", "hello vishal"));
    printf("SET: %s\n", reply->str);
    freeReplyObject(reply);
    redisClusterFree(cc);
    return 0;
}
```

On running the program, I'm getting segmentation fault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004009ed in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe508) at cluster-example.c:30
30          printf("SET: %s\n", reply->str);
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.7-18.el6_9.2.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.7-18.el6_9.2.x86_64
(gdb) bt f
#0  0x00000000004009ed in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe508) at cluster-example.c:30
        timeout = {tv_sec = 1, tv_usec = 500000}
        cc = 0x7ffff7fdb010
        reply = 0x0
```

`redisReply *` is having NULL value which is resulting in the segmentation fault when I use this pointer in `printf()`.

What's wrong in the program?

**Edit 1**

I've updated a portion of my program after the suggestion from @Stamatis Liatsos:

```
    reply = (redisReply*)(redisClusterCommand(cc,"SET %s %s", "foo", "hello vishal"));
if(cc->err)
    printf("\n[%s::%d]Error: %s\n", __FILE__,__LINE__,cc->errstr);
else
    printf("SET: %s\n", reply->str);
```

Here's the output which I'm getting:

**`[cluster-example.c::31]Error: ctx get by node is null`**

Comment: As far as i can see the redisClusterCommand() could return a null redisReply and in that case your cc variable should have an error that you could retrieve by cc->errstr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this exact issue over [here](https://github.com/vipshop/hiredis-vip/issues/102).

We have to setup the context to use slots before connecting.

```
struct timeval timeout = { 1, 500000 }; // 1.5 seconds
redisClusterContext *cc = redisClusterContextInit();
redisClusterSetOptionAddNodes(cc, "172.16.129.68:6379");
redisClusterSetOptionConnectTimeout(cc, timeout);
redisClusterSetOptionRouteUseSlots(cc);  //The function that has to be called.
redisClusterConnect2(cc);
if (cc != NULL && cc->err) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", cc->errstr);
    // handle error
exit(-1);
}
```